# Plotly Dash dropdown showing a received value before I click

Tags: plotly-dash

I am starting to code with Dash and I'm trying to achieve two chained dropdown boxes.

The topmost will show a list of date strings (fetched from MongoDB)

Upon selecting one of these dates in the topmost dropdown I'd like for all articles with that date to appear in the second one.

The code I'll post below does it but ideally I would like for the first article to show in the bottom dropdown, while right now I need to actively click for the first choice to appear in either dropdown.

Not including the imports and MongoDB collection (artcoll) code above it.

```
# Build Components
app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.SOLAR])
mydates = dcc.Dropdown(
    id="field-dropdown", options=[], value=None
)  # will be populated by article dates
myarticles = dcc.Dropdown(
    id="results-dropdown", options=[], value=None
)  # will be populated by articles for a given date

# Define the layout of the app
app.layout = dbc.Container(
    [
        dbc.Row(
            [dbc.Col([dbc.NavbarBrand("My Dashboard")], width=3)],
            justify="center",
        ),
        dbc.Row([dbc.Col([mydates], width=3)]),
        dbc.Row([dbc.Col([myarticles], width=3)]),
    ],
    fluid=True,
)

# Define the callback to populate the dates dropdown
@app.callback(Output("field-dropdown", "options"), Input("field-dropdown", "value"))
def populate_field_dropdown(selected_value):
    """Get distinct values from the MongoDB collection articledatepub field"""
    art_dates = artcoll.distinct("articledatepub")
    options = [{"label": f, "value": f} for f in art_dates]
    return options


# Define the callback to populate the issues dropdown
@app.callback(Output("results-dropdown", "options"), Input("field-dropdown", "value"))
def populate_results_dropdown(selected_value):
    """show issues for the selected date in dropdown"""
    print(f"first dropdown passed {selected_value} to second one")
    if selected_value is None:
        return []
    # Fetch the documents in the MongoDB collection
    mongofilter = {"articledatepub": {"$eq": selected_value}}
    documents = artcoll.find(filter=mongofilter)
    options = [
        {"label": str(d["articleid"]), "value": str(d["_id"])} for d in documents
    ]
    return options


# Define the main function to run the app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an `Output` to the callback for your bottom dropdown that targets the "value" prop of the dropdown.

So your `populate_results_dropdown` callback could have two outputs like this:

```
Output("results-dropdown", "options"),
Output("results-dropdown", "value"),
```

One sets the option, the other the selected value.

If you want to make the selected value the first value in your `options` list you can return this:

```
return options, options[0]["value"]
```

I'm assuming `options` could be empty, so you would need to check that the `options` list is not empty before you access it like above.

The same idea applies for your first callback as well btw. If you want to select a value automatically based on the data you get back you can do it in the same way.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH !!! Learned more from your replay than from reading a dozen tutorials :) Now if only I could understand why Visual Studio debugger fails with a No module named "nameofmoduleyouredebugging" while both Visual Studio and command line execute the program perfectly (and all other python proograms are debugged just fine) :(

Comment: Glad to help :). I personally don't use vscode and just put breakpoint() calls directly in the code and debug in the terminal, but I googled and maybe this thread is useful https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-configure-a-debugger-for-dash-in-vs-code/29960/2.

Comment: Based on that reply it was just enough to add "application = app.server" right after  the app = Dash(__name__) line !!!! Not understanding what this is about but VERY happy. Owe you a pizza !!! Cheers from Rome